# Incorrect display of datagridview images c#

Tags: image, datagridview

I am creating a Bitmap object in a class. But when loading datagridview, no images show.

```
private Bitmap _images;
public Bitmap images { get => _images; set => _images = CreateImage(); }
public Bitmap CreateImage()
 {
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(image);
    using (var response = request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (var str = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            return (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(str);
        }
    }
}
```

But the problem is that when I fill the cell with a new single-type picture from the method, by some miracle the pictures that are saved in the class begin to be displayed. But the new picture is not displayed in any way.How it works?

```
dataGridViewList.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dataGridViewList.DataSource = listcoinsmarket;
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewList.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    WebRequest myRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/premium/png-256-thumb/digi-byte-1-854689.png");
    using (var response = myRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        using (var str = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            dataGridViewList.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value = Bitmap.FromStream(str);
        }
    }
}
```

How do I display pictures when the DataSource is executed?

Comment: In my tests using the second snippet of posted code, the images do appear in the cells. There seems to be an issue with the images getting duplicated, however, the image DOES show. Is it possible the image is bigger than the cell and you only see a small portion of the image? Have you tried to set the grid’s image column’s `ImageLayout` property? Something like… `imgCol.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch.` This should fill the cell with the entire image.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewList.Rows.Count; i++)
{
     dataGridViewList.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value = null;
} 
 
I get the same result even after I redefine the fields as null. After that, the pictures start to be displayed. Also, when the code is loaded for the first time, there are red crosses, which means that there is no image. But after the cycle, the pictures start to appear.

Comment: @JohnG This is a screenshot of the items without cycle through https://prnt.sc/10uj4u2. This is after https://prnt.sc/10uj51x

Comment: It is difficult to follow what you are describing. The first code snippet shows a function that returns a `Bitmap` image. However, where and how is this code related to your issue? In the second code snippet, this seems different than what you describe and your pictures show. The second snippet of code is using the “same” image for all cells. So, it is unclear how this code could produce the picture you posted. I suggest you post the code that is causing the problem since in my tests the images display as expected.

Comment: Let me explain to you.  Bitmap is a class variable like other variables of this class.  I create a list of class items after bind the list to my Datagridview.  And after that all elements are displayed correctly except for images.  I can only display them using the loop I showed above.  Without it, the image column does not display images, only red crosses.  Normally, the images should be displayed immediately after binding to the datagridview, just like text data.  Do you have images displayed in datagridview without using the example loop code that I used above?

Comment: Your question… _”Do you have images displayed in datagridview without using the example loop code that I used above?”_ … YES. Images display as expected.